# Get string x Value from Data Point in Chart

Tags: c#

Im plotting Data as XY Chart in C#/Ms Forms .net4.8 . My X value is a string, Y value a double.

`chRtt.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(rttPoint.IdSystem, rttPoint.UV);`

Now i want to get the X and Y value when I click the datapoint in the chart. At the moment im using HitTestResult but it doesnt work for strings and therefore only returns 0 for the X value.

```
HitTestResult hit = chRtt.HitTest(e.X, e.Y, true);
if (hit.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
   {
        chRtt.Series["Series1"].Points[hit.PointIndex].Color = Color.Black;
        MessageBox.Show(hit.Series + ": " + hit.Object);
    }
```

Is there a way to click into the chart and get the acutal string belonging to the datapoint Im plotting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
if you have multiples series give series[0], so it will the same result.

```
_x_value = chRtt.Series["Series1"].Points[hit.PointIndex].XValue.ToString();
if(_x_value ="0")
_x_value  =   chRtt.Series["Series1"].Points[hit.PointIndex].AxisLabel.ToString();
```